# Hosting an asp.net and a web api my self

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Basically I have an exe, that controls a pizzaria, it should be extended to allow users to choose a pizza slice from the web. The application I have, keeps track of what slices are available at the moment, and only show them on the site.

I've made an asp.net web api project and am hosting that inside my application.
(Owin, self hosting asp.net web api;-) My problem is how to configure the IAppBuilder, to go the normal MVC steps looking for my site, when the url, requested didn't go to an api controller.

```
  public class Startup {
      public static void Configuration(IAppBuilder app) {
          app.UseStaticFiles();
          var apiConfig = new HttpConfiguration();
          apiConfig.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
          app.UseWebApi(apiConfig);
          // THIS IS WHERE I NEED THE app to look through 
          // my MVC controllers, to get the view..
          app.Run(async context => { 
             await context.Response.WriteAsync(" My First dummy OWIN App");
          });
      }
   }
```

(I think I just need to figure out how to get the mvc controllers to get the request.. )
Thanks any help will be appreciated, with this, my first asp/web project in 15 years..

Comment: have you tried to use URL like below:

abc.com/api/controller

Comment: yes, and the api/Slises gives me the correct awnser in json.
but I cannot get the HomeController, to simply show a webpage.
the SlicesController:ApiController, works nicely.

Comment: Where is your route config, should be in app_start folder

Comment: I think it is due to using .net and not .net core. Since Shawn claims that to be the case here: https://wildermuth.com/2016/05/10/Writing-API-Controllers-in-ASP-NET-MVC-6 
And I am just taking his course